# Copy a .exe file to a remote PC

Tags: batch-file

I want to copy a `.exe` file from my laptop on the remote PC list with a batch file.
I try this:

```
copy D:\file.exe \\remotepc\d$
```

from a single PC but I receive the follow error message:

> ```
> the syntax of the command is incorrect
> ```

Comment: You are missing a slash. `D:\file.exe \\remotepc\d$`

Comment: @Squashman, this was actually there but parsed to a single `\ `, because of poor formatting...

Comment: hi,                                                                                                                 Whitch is the parameter to copy a file for a remote pc list ?

Comment: @C.Bogdan, if you have a list of computers in a text file, then use `FOR` command with the `/F` option to read that list and then execute your copy command with the `FOR` variable.